# Why do I have a $RECYCLE.BIN directory in my \boot although I never used Windows on my Notebook?

Tags: 18.04, wine

Recently I had to delete some old boot files manually, because my '\boot' directory became to small and I realised that there is a '$RECYCLE.BIN' directory inside my '\boot' with a 'desktop.ini' inside. I never ever used Windows on my Notebook, but sometimes wine. Could it be that wine has something to do with it, or is something strange going on in my system?
And if wine does things like this, why can it change anything inside '\boot'?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (the only one on my system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those directories are probably leftovers from an installation routine of the seller of the notebook. It came with preinstalled OS.